# jquery animation is complete across the board

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I ran into a problem that comes with jquery animation. I am having the user be able to click a button and based off that button direction they click it slides all the **list**(li) elements to that opposing direction. The problem comes in that I have it set to wrap-around inside a div, so when a list element ends on one side it getting the animation to slide off the div sight but getting the css style attribute set to the opposite side off the screen so it can be ready to scroll down for the next button click. But when the user clicks the button multiple times it queues up all the elements on top of each other because the animation hasn't finished. So then I attached the **stop()** animation to the elements, but then the second problem comes in that when the user clicks the button fast multiple times it, The elements never get to wrap around, they will just stay dissappeared until you click the button slowly or if you start pressing the button faster after some of them are dissappeared then start back slow then only the ones that were visible when slow are still wrapping in the div until the next wrap around:

**quick example:**

```
function Rotate(){
    $("li.headline").each(function(){
      var left= $(this).css("left");
      left=left-100;
      if(left>99){
         $(this).stop().animation({left:left}, 'slow', function(){
         $(this).css("left",left);});
      }else{
         $(this).stop().animation({left:left}, 'slow', function(){
         $(this).css("left",max);}); //max is the max "left" calculated from all list items
      }
    });
 }
$("button.next").click(function(){
Rotate();
});
```

could someone help me

**html/css example**

```
#scroll{
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
width:300px
}
.headline{
position:absolute;
float:left
}

  <div id="scroll">
    <ul>
      <li  class="headline"><a>First</a>
      <li  class="headline"><a>Second</a>
      <li  class="headline"><a>Third</a>
      <li  class="headline"><a>Fourth</a>
      <li  class="headline"><a>Fifth</a>
    </ul>
  <div>
```

Comment: Could you post an example of your HTML as well? A link to a jsFiddle.net sample would be extremely helpful in reproducing the behaviour that you're seeing.

Comment: Still having trouble duplicating the issue. Could you check your CSS? I don't think you meant two #scroll styles. I've pasted your code here, http://jsfiddle.net/4gR8S/, but can't duplicate the problem. Please update and share the updated link with the repro.

Comment: you're right I didn't I was able to fix the problem by adding a check in the "if" condition. will post with answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the problem by adding a extra check in the **if** condition as so

```
var index;//this is the current li at the head that is incremented by the button click 
//and updated outside this function
$("li.headline").each(function(i){ //added i to get the current index the each is on
if(left>99&&index==i){ 
     $(this).stop(true, false).animation({left:left}, 'slow', function(){ //also made the first true
      //and second false, so the animation wouldn't rush across the screen but true so it wouldn't
      // build up the queue
     $(this).css("left",left);}); 
  }else{ 
     $(this).stop(true, false).animation({left:left}, 'slow', function(){ 
     $(this).css("left",max);}); //max is the max "left" calculated from all list items 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$(this).stop(true, true) // remainder of your code
```

It will clear the animation queue for the matched element and complete the animation. The default for both is false, which means any queued animations are still run (only the current animation is stopped) and the current animation is not completed.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: actually by adding the stop(true, true) instead it makes the ones <99 zoom across the div if the button is pressed too fast